# Why does the following set always have finite measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $E$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and the Lebesgue outer measure $m^*(E) = \infty$, then why does $$E_n = E \cap [-n,n], \ \ \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$ have finite measure?

What if $n = \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\infty \notin \mathbb N$.   The statement is that for any finite N, any measurable subset of $[-n,n]$  is finite, and that follows from monotonicity: $m(E_n) \le m([-n,n])=2n$

Answer (score 0):

If $ n=\infty $, then $ n\not\in\mathbb N $.